# GWT 1.4 TO 2.0 UiBinder

Tags: gwt, gwt2

I am upgrading a project with around 60 java classes, from 1.4 to 2.0 . Apart from replacing deprecated functions, adding generics, will converting the whole project into UI Binder approach i.e. XML and Corresponding working Java classes, be recommended. Or shall i go on adding new UI requirments using Ui Binder and leaving the existing code as it is?

Answer (score 3):

I'd go with UiBinder all the way - that way you'll get most from the benefits of UiBinder (like nice CSS handling/minification/obfuscation). And the rewrite will be a good chance to look at the older code and do some refactoring - like reorganizing the Widgets to be more lightweight (more pure HTML via UiBinder, less Widgets, but don't go overboard ;)), maybe introducing [`History`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/History.html) support, i18n, etc. I had the same dilemma some time ago and took the full UiBinder approach and don't regret it ;) It makes it easier to work with the code too - since the UI code is consistent.